# Rails - Model Method for Default DateTime Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In the DB, everything is in DateTime format.  However, in my Post model, I would like to specify a default date and time format that is output whenever records are GET.  Since this is for an API, I think I'll go with Twitter's format, unless anyone has any better suggestions:

```
"created_at":"Thu, 06 Oct 2011 19:41:12 +0000"
```

Comment: How are you serializing the data?

Comment: I'm unclear as to how it is being serialized.  I have a Rails app, with a postgresDB DateTime column.  Whatever the default serialization is that comes with that stack.

Answer (score 0):

You could try overriding the as_json method on your model:

```
def as_json(options)
  super(:methods => [:formatted_date])
end
```

Then have a method that formats the date they way you want

```
def formatted_date
  # format date string here
end
```

This is assuming your controller is rendering json like `format.json { render :json => @object }`.

I would suggest using a builder to serialize data ([jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) or [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers))